# Makefile rule not a target when using eval

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that extracts a tar file into a variable number of folders which are determined at runtime (in the example below, this is hard coded):

```
firstTarget: start
.PHONY: start

DIRS = d1 d2 d3

TAR_FILES = $(wildcard ?.tar)
TAR_FILE_NAMES := $(TAR_FILES:%.tar=%)
FILES = $(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(TAR_FILE_NAMES:%=$_/%.txt))

define AddRule
DIR = $(1)
$(DIR)/%.txt: %.tar
    @echo $(1) $(DIR) $$@ $$< $$*
    @mkdir -p $(DIR)
    @tar -xvf $$< > /dev/null
    @mv $$*.txt $(DIR)
endef
$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule, $_)))
#$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule, $_)))

start: $(FILES)
    @echo "Finished"

setup:
    @touch a.txt
    @tar -cvf a.tar a.txt > /dev/null
    @rm a.txt

clean:
    @rm -rf d1/ d2/ d3/
```

Rules are generated at runtime for each of the variable cases and parsed as make instructions using `eval` and `call`.

Note the following lines:

```
$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule, $_)))
#$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule, $_)))
```

When the second line is commented out, I get the following output and error:

```
d2 d1 d1/a.txt a.tar a
d3 d2 d2/a.txt a.tar a
make: *** No rule to make target 'd3/a.txt', needed by 'start'.  Stop.
```

When I run make with `-pRr` I see the following output for the rule for `d3/a.txt`:

```
# Not a target:
d3/a.txt:
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  File does not exist.
#  File has not been updated.
```

Compare this to the rule for `d1/a.txt`:

```
d1/a.txt: a.tar
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'a'
#  Last modified 2016-02-18 09:36:24
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := d1/a.txt
# automatic
# % := 
# automatic
# * := a
# automatic
# + := a.tar
# automatic
# | := 
# automatic
# < := a.tar
# automatic
# ^ := a.tar
# automatic
# ? := a.tar
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/25=4%
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 18):
    @echo  d2 d1 $@ $< $*
    @mkdir -p d1
    @tar -xvf $< > /dev/null
    @mv $*.txt d1
```

With the second line added, meaning that each rule is called and evaluated twice, it works fine:

```
d2 d1 d1/a.txt a.tar a
d3 d2 d2/a.txt a.tar a
d1 d3 d3/a.txt a.tar a
Finished
```

The rule for `d3/a.txt` is also similar to the above rule for `d1/a.txt` when viewed through `make -pRr`.

It's worth noting that in the rule I'm outputting the following:

```
@echo $(1) $(DIR) $$@ $$< $$*
```

And now the questions:

1. Why doesn't the rule for `d3` get evaluated properly?
2. Why does $(1) not equal $(DIR) when in the rule? This is odd since $(1) is assigned to $(DIR).
3. Why does calling and evaluating the rule make it work fine?

If you want to repeat the problem, run `make setup` first, then `make`.

**Update 1: 18/02/2016**

The answer by @DevSolar solves the problem above but has made me realise my test case wasn't a perfect representation of the real problem. In the real problem, the parameter to the dynamic rule isn't at the beginning of the target:

```
FILES = $(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(TAR_FILE_NAMES:%=somedir/$_/%.txt))

define AddRule
somedir/$(1)/%.txt: %.tar
    @echo $(1) $$@ $$< $$*
    @mkdir -p somedir/$(1)
    @tar -xvf $$< > /dev/null
    @mv $$*.txt $(1)
endef
```

Note that the target is now `somedir/$(1)/%.txt: %.tar`. This results in the following error in make 3.81:

```
Makefile:17: warning: overriding commands for target `somedir'
Makefile:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `somedir'
Makefile:17: warning: overriding commands for target `somedir'
Makefile:17: warning: ignoring old commands for target `somedir'
```

Interestingly, make 4.1 has something else to say:

```
Makefile:17: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
Makefile:17: warning: overriding recipe for target 'somedir/'
Makefile:17: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'somedir/'
Makefile:17: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
Makefile:17: warning: overriding recipe for target 'somedir/'
Makefile:17: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'somedir/'
Makefile:17: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make: *** No rule to make target 'somedir/d1/a.txt', needed by 'start'.  Stop.
```

Neither have helped me figure out the cause.

Comment: @DevSolar When you copy and paste you have to convert spaces to tabs. Sadly SO doesn't preserve them.

Comment: Facepalm.... {expletive deleted} /me stupid. Thx. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597998/eval-function-does-not-execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to admit I have never *really* understood the exact rules by which the more advanced features of `make` operate (since when I started being interested in them, I switched to CMake instead).

So I cannot provide you with an elaborate "why" (does this happen), but only a "how" (do I fix this).

**Don't assign `DIR = $(1)`, use `$(1)` directly:**

```
define AddRule
$(1)/%.txt: %.tar
    @mkdir -p $(1)
    @tar -xvf $$< > /dev/null
    @mv $$*.txt $(1)
endef
$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule, $_)))
```

This works as expected. I can only assume that the local assignment does not work together with however `make` does handle `define`s.

> As @user657267 pointed out in a comment:
>
> The reason `DIR = $(1)` (or more precisely `$(DIR)`) fails is because `eval` expands everything *before* the content is expanded as makefile syntax. Replacing `$(DIR)` with `$$(DIR)` also fixes the issue.

---

**UPDATE:**

Solved your updated problem by having a look at what `$(1)` actually resolves to in the `define`:

```
define AddRule
$(warning '$(1)')
...
```

Output:

```
Makefile:21: ' d1'
Makefile:21: ' d2'
Makefile:21: ' d3'
```

Culprit:

```
$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule, $_)))
                                            ^
```

Solution:

```
$(foreach _, $(DIRS), $(eval $(call AddRule,$_)))
```

(Note the removed space before `$_`, which became part of the `$(1)` token.)

Comment: Thanks. This solves the test case, but also has helped me to realise that the test case isn't representative of my real world case. The target being created with `eval` has the parameter in the middle of the path. I've updated the question with some additional information.

Comment: Wow! Nice job. I didn't know about `$(warning)` so that's good to know too. I remember now that the [makefile docs for call](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html) warns about whitespace (last paragraph). I'm surprised that it takes the whitespace before the token, though.

Comment: @Jon: Maintenance coder by profession. When something doesn't work, the first thing I look for is always some form of "print" function to check the assumptions. ;-)

Comment: The reason `DIR = $(1)` (or more precisely `$(DIR)`) fails is because `eval` expands everything *before* the content is expanded as makefile syntax, replacing `$(DIR)` with `$$(DIR)` also fixes the issue.

Comment: @Jon: Check the comment above, it's the explanation for the behavour. You doubled all the `$$` except those for `$(DIR)`. ;-)

Comment: Yup, already seen. Upvoted the comment. Nice to have the root cause.