# Makefile:108: *** recipe commences before first target

Tags: linux, makefile, eval, gnu-make, gnu

GNU Make 4.1 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Below is the `Makefile`:

```
# Project variables
PROJECT_NAME ?= todobackend
ORG_NAME ?= shamdockerhub
REPO_NAME ?= todobackend

# File names
DEV_COMPOSE_FILE := docker/dev/docker-compose.yml
REL_COMPOSE_FILE := docker/release/docker-compose.yml

# Docker compose project names
REL_PROJECT := $(PROJECT_NAME)$(BUILD_ID)
DEV_PROJECT := $(REL_PROJECT)dev

# Check and inspect logic
INSPECT := $$(docker-compose -p $$1 -f $$2 ps -q $$3 | xargs -I ARGS docker inspect -f "{{ .State.ExitCode }}" ARGS)

CHECK := @bash -c '\
    if [[ $(INSPECT) -ne 0 ]]; \
    then exit $(INSPECT); fi' VALUE

# Use these settings to specify a custom Docker registry
DOCKER_REGISTRY ?= docker.io

APP_SERVICE_NAME := app

.PHONY: test build release clean tag

test: # Run unit & integration test cases
    ${INFO} "Pulling latest images..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) pull
    ${INFO} "Building images..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) build cache
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) build --pull test
    ${INFO} "Ensuring database is ready..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) run --rm agent
    ${INFO} "Running tests..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) up test
    @ docker cp $$(docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q test):/reports/. reports
    ${CHECK} ${DEV_PROJECT} ${DEV_COMPOSE_FILE} test
    ${INFO} "Testing complete"

build: # Create deployable artifact and copy to ../target folder
    ${INFO} "Creating builder image..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) build builder
    ${INFO} "Building application artifacts..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) up builder
    ${CHECK} ${DEV_PROJECT} ${DEV_COMPOSE_FILE} builder
    ${INFO} "Copying artifacts to target folder..."
    @ docker cp $$(docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q builder):/wheelhouse/. target
    ${INFO} "Build complete"

release: # Creates release environment, bootstrap the environment  
    ${INFO} "Building images..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) build webroot
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) build app
    ${INFO} "Ensuring database is ready..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) run --rm agent
    ${INFO} "Collecting static files..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) run --rm app manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    ${INFO} "Running database migrations..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) run --rm app manage.py migrate --noinput
    ${INFO} "Pull external image and build..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) build --pull nginx
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) pull test
    ${INFO} "Running acceptance tests..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) up test
    ${CHECK} $(REL_PROJECT) $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) test
    @ docker cp $$(docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q test):/reports/. reports
    ${INFO} "Acceptance testing complete"

clean:
    ${INFO} "Destroying development environment..."
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) kill
    @ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) rm -f -v
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) kill
    @ docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) rm -f -v
    @ docker images -q -f dangling=true -f label=application=$(REPO_NAME) | xargs -I ARGS docker rmi -f ARGS
    ${INFO} "Clean complete"

tag:
    $(INFO) "Tagging release image with tags $(TAG_ARGS)"
    @ $(foreach tag, $(TAG_ARGS), docker tag $(IMAGE_ID) $(DOCKER_REGISTRY)/$(ORG_NAME)/$(REPO_NAME):$(tag);)
    ${INFO} "Tagging complete"


# Cosmetics 
YELLOW := "\e[1;33m"
NC := "\e[0m"

# Shell functions
INFO := @bash -c '\
    printf $(YELLOW); \
    echo "=> $$1"; \
    printf $(NC)' VALUE

# Get container id of application service container
APP_CONTAINER_ID := $$(docker-compose -p $(REL_PROJECT) -f $(REL_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q $(APP_SERVICE_NAME))

# Get image id of application service
IMAGE_ID := $$(docker inspect -f '{{ .Image }}' $(APP_CONTAINER_ID))

# Extract tag arguments
ifeq (tag, $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    TAG_ARGS := $(wordlist 2, $(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
    ifeq ($(TAG_ARGS),)
        $(error You must specify a tag)
    endif
    $(eval $(TAG_ARGS):;@:) # line 108 Do not interpret "0.1 latest whatever" as make target files 
endif
```

---

Below is the error on running make command:

```
$ make tag 0.1 latest $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
Makefile:108: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Line 108, purpose of `$(eval $(TAG_ARGS):;@:)` to convey that `0.1 latest $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)` are not `make` targets.

---

Why `$(eval $(TAG_ARGS):;@:)` gives error?

Comment: `make tag 0.1 latest ...` normally means "update the targets `tag`, `0.1`, `latest` ...".  There is a hack against that, but (did you notice?) someone commented it out!

Comment: because you commented it out?

Comment: @mosvy I know that it is commented, I do don't comment then error at eval

Comment: You should edit your question so it is about about the real error that you're debugging, not some "red herring" which happens when you comment out the non-working line.

Comment: @kaz Question edited... with eval

Comment: Tagging me in a completely unrelated Makefile question to point me in the direction of this question isn't good style. I don't see how this question is "related" to the other one other than being about Makefiles. Also, you could have made some effort to make your example minimal, instead of dumping your whole Makefile on us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular error happens because your `$(eval ...)` line is indented by a TAB (something that it's hidden by this horribly broken web interface).

Example:

```
$ make -f <(printf '\t$(eval foo:;echo yup)')
/dev/fd/63:1: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

# now with spaces instead of TAB
$ make -f <(printf '    $(eval foo:;echo yup)')
echo yup
yup
```

The error is documented in the `make` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#Error-Messages):

> `recipe commences before first target. Stop.`
>
> This means the first thing in the makefile seems to be part of a
>        recipe: it begins with a *recipe prefix character* and doesn't appear
>        to be a legal `make` directive (such as a variable assignment).
>        Recipes must always be associated with a target.

The "recipe prefix character" is TAB by default.

```
$ make -f <(printf '\tfoo')
/dev/fd/63:1: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

It doesn't have to be the "first thing in the makefile", though: the same error will trigger after a number of rules, if preceded by a directive like a macro assignment or such:

```
$ make -f <(printf 'all:;\nkey=val\n\tfoo')
/dev/fd/63:3: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

And even if a macro expands to an empty string, GNU make will not consider empty a line containing just macros expanding to empty strings:

```
$ make -f <(printf '\t\nfoo:;@:')
$ make -f <(printf '\t$(info foo)\nfoo:;@:')
/dev/fd/63:1: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
$ make -f <(printf '   $(info foo)\nfoo:;@:')
foo
```

Comment: How to avoid this tab issue

Comment: replace the tab with spaces?

Comment: Why tab issue only for  that line of code? Why tab is not creating issue for other lines of code?

Comment: all the other lines indented with tabs are either recipes or directives like `foo := bar` and the `$(error ...)` is skipped by the `ifdef`. That's already explained in the manual quote from my answer.

Comment: does ifeq conditional directive execute before executing tag target?

Comment: make has to know all the dependencies, etc before doing anything, so it's first parsing the whole file, like perl, etc. It does not "execute" it line by line, like bash.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this problem.  I put your last `ifeq` statement into a makefile and it works fine for me with GNU make 4.1 and 4.2.1.  There must be something more unusual about your situation.

The classic way to debug issues with `eval` is to duplicate the line and replace the `eval` with `info`; this way make will print out exactly what it sees.  Often this will show you what is wrong.

There are other confusing things about this makefile.

First, why are you using `eval` here in the first place?  Why not just write the rule directly?  There's nothing wrong with:

```
$(TAG_ARGS):;@:
```

no need to wrap it in an `eval`.

Second, why are you using `:=` then escaping the variables?  Why not just use `=` instead and not bother with the escapes?

```
INSPECT = $(docker-compose -p $1 -f $2 ps -q $3 | xargs -I ARGS docker inspect -f "{{ .State.ExitCode }}" ARGS)
```

works just fine.

Finally, I strongly urge you to not add `@` to your recipes.  It makes debugging makefiles very difficult and frustrating.  Instead consider using a method such as [Managing Recipe Echoing](http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/) to handle this.